# Not able to attach debugger to the outlook add-in code for desktop outlook app

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, outlook-web-addins, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

Tried to attach the debugger to outlook add-in code generated by yo office generator not able to do so, below is the error and the launch configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dev server has been started and available before running the debugger in VSCode. See [Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension#:%7E:text=When%20your%20add%2Din%20loads,the%20menu%20to%20begin%20debugging.) for more information.

Note, in Outlook the debugger works for task panes only.

You may find the [Debug add-ins on Windows using Visual Studio Code and Microsoft Edge WebView2 (Chromium-based)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium) page helpful.

Comment: These links may be helpful: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium